# Javaagent not printing

Tags: java, javassist, javaagents

I'm using Javassist.
Here's my code:

```
public class JavaAgent {
        public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
            inst.addTransformer((ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) -> {
                if(className.endsWith("javafx/stage/Stage")) {
                    System.out.println(1);
                    ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
                    System.out.println(2);
                }
                return null;
            });
        }
    }
```

I found there a strange situation, my output is:

> 1

Why?

---

EDIT:

To be sure it's not an exception issue, I've added catcher, like this:

```
    if(className.endsWith("javafx/stage/Stage")) {
        try {
            System.out.println(1);
            ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
            System.out.println(2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("EX!");
        }
    }
```

And output is still the same.

Comment: try to catch/log exceptions

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Not familiar with `Instrumentation` but it seems doubtful that `className` would ever end with `javafx/stage/Stage`

Comment: My Java is: 1.8.0_162

Comment: @Brian As I said previously, I got "1" in output, so this is not a problem

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. I forgot to copy JavaAgent's lib folder along with JavaAgent.jar.

The strange thing is that there was no exception info unless I declared

```
ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
```

outside premain() function.